# VK API requests.exceptions.SSLError и Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Начал изучать API vk и сразу столкнулся вот с такой проблемой:

```
import requests


def main():

    r = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=1')
    print(r)

main()
```

Вроде простейший запрос, если вставить его в строку браузера он работает.

Интерпретатор питона возвращает следующую ошибку:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.vk.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /method/users.get?user_ids=1(Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Study\py\API\vk\vkapi.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\Study\py\API\vk\vkapi.py", line 6, in main
    r = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=1')
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\БУХ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.vk.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /method/users.get?user_ids=1(Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),))
```

Попытался найти ответ на свой вопрос в сети, но однозначных ответов нет.

Что-то мне подсказывает что ему что-то не нравится в SSL...

Может быть уже кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, или  не проблемой вовсе.

Очень интересно понять что не так.

Вообще задача немного другая, с использованием токена и прочего, но так как ошибка и в простом примере и в примере с токеном одинаковая не стал усложнять вопрос.

Comment: related: [Python Requests throwing SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10667960/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Тоже некоторое время назад появилась такая ошибка, что-то не так у vk стало с https/ssl видимо. К сожалению, подробно не разобрался, но лечится это отключением ssl:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=1', verify=False)
```

Но он начнет выдавать предупреждения каждый раз. Тут расссказано, как их подавить:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981545/suppress-insecurerequestwarning-unverified-https-request-is-being-made-in-pytho

Comment: Спасибо, сразу заработало! 

Я пытался передавать verify=False в параметрах, но видимо по неопытности сделал неправильно. 

Я делал вот так:
r = requests.get(base, params={'access_token' : token, 'owner_id': owner_id, 'count': 100, 'offset': 0, "**verify":False** })

А работает вот так:

r = requests.get(base, params={'access_token' : token, 'owner_id': owner_id, 'count': 100, 'offset': 0}, **verify = False**)

Comment: @AlekseyKravchenko топор—это слишком радикальное средство для лечения головной боли. К слову, сейчас проблем с сертификатами нет.